# bootstrap popups with asp content not working

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

using bootstrap popups modal in asp content pages. my content page can inherit css for all asp server controls but when i am trying to use bootstrap popups in asp:contents it does not popup. I also cannot find where the issue is since debugger cannot catch the issue.

One of the bootstrap instance not working is datepicker. Using the following code in asp:content. It does not work. I have tried this content in the table row and out of table. I am not sure what could be issue

```
<div>
<div class="container">
        <div class="hero-unit">
            <input  type="text" placeholder="click to show datepicker"  id="example1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Load jQuery and bootstrap datepicker scripts -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // When the document is ready
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#example1').datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
            });

        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show us the code of the modal and how you open the modal?

Comment: Use your browser's JavaScript console/developer tools to see what client-side errors you're likely experiencing; these are normally launched using the F12 key while your browser is the active window.

Comment: Just looking at the bit of code you've included, it looks like (at a minimum) you're missing the bootstrap.js script, which the bootstrap-datepicker.js script relies on.

Comment: They were added in masterpages, I have also tried adding them in this particular web page. It still does not work.

Comment: bootstrap does not have a date-picker. What date-picker for bootstrap are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine now. Here is the code how it worked.

```js
$(function () {
            $('#dp1').datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
            });
        });

function copy_data(val){
                    var a = document.getElementById('dp1').value
                    document.getElementById("<%=txtdob2.ClientID%>").value=a
                }
```

```html
<div>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Click to show Datepicker" id="dp1" class="form-control input-sm" onblur ="copy_data(this)"/>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="txtdob2" runat="server" />
                                    
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDOB" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
```

however now I have a different problem. I am unable to save the data from Textbox to the server. Since it is a client based Textbox, it does not save to server. I have also tried using the Hidden value but it's not working.